# QGIS python: QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am currently reading the PyQGIS Cookbook for developers. While I was reading [chapter 5](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html), Using Raster Layers, I had the idea of adding a TIFF file within QGIS project. The TIFF file has the projection EPSG:2964, and my other layers (just one) have the projection 4326.

When I run the following Python code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read('SOME_PATH/start-project.qgz')
```

I am getting this output from the terminal, and the script has been exited:
`QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication`

Any idea of the cause of this problem?

The version of my QGIS:

- QGIS version: 3.32.3-Lima
- QGIS code revision: 67d46100b5b
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- Python version: 3.9.5
- GDAL/OGR version: 3.3.2
- PROJ version: 8.1.1
- EPSG Registry database version: v10.028 (2021-07-07)
- GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
- SQLite version: 3.35.2
- PDAL version: 2.3.0
- PostgreSQL client version: unknown
- SpatiaLite version: 5.0.1
- QWT version: 6.1.6
- QScintilla2 version: 2.11.5
- OS version: macOS 14.0